# Printing a mixed type dictionary with format in python

Tags: python, string, printing, dictionary, format

I have

```
d = {'a':'Ali', 'b':2341, 'c':0.2424242421, 'p':3.141592}
```

I want to print it out to std but I want format the numbers, like remove the excessive decimal places, something like

```
{'a':'Ali', 'b':2341, 'c':0.24, 'p':3.14}
```

obviously I can go through all the items and see if they are a 'type' I want to format and format them and print the results,

But is there a better way to `format` all the numbers in a dictionary when `__str__()` ing or in someway getting a string out to print?

EDIT:
I am looking for some magic like:

```
'{format only floats and ignore the rest}'.format(d)
```

or something from the `yaml` world or similar.

Comment: Check out my updated solution, may be that's what you wanted.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `round` for rounding the floats to a given precision. To identify floats use `isinstance`:

```
>>> {k:round(v,2) if isinstance(v,float) else v for k,v in d.iteritems()}
{'a': 'Ali', 'p': 3.14, 'c': 0.24, 'b': 2341}
```

help on `round`:

```
>>> print round.__doc__
round(number[, ndigits]) -> floating point number

Round a number to a given precision in decimal digits (default 0 digits).
This always returns a floating point number.  Precision may be negative.
```

**Update:**

You can create a subclass of `dict` and override the behaviour of `__str__`:

```
class my_dict(dict):                                              
    def __str__(self):
        return str({k:round(v,2) if isinstance(v,float) else v 
                                                    for k,v in self.iteritems()})
...     
>>> d = my_dict({'a':'Ali', 'b':2341, 'c':0.2424242421, 'p':3.141592})
>>> print d
{'a': 'Ali', 'p': 3.14, 'c': 0.24, 'b': 2341}
>>> "{}".format(d)
"{'a': 'Ali', 'p': 3.14, 'c': 0.24, 'b': 2341}"
>>> d
{'a': 'Ali', 'p': 3.141592, 'c': 0.2424242421, 'b': 2341}
```

Comment: I always like the one-liners, and I didn't know the `{}` sugar that gives you back a dictionary.

Comment: @Ali This is called dictionary comprehension and was introduced in py2.7.

Comment: Python 3 renamed dict.iteritems -> dict.items

Answer (score 0):

To convert float to two decimal places, do this:

`a = 3.141592`
`b = float("%.2f" % a) #b will have 2 decimal places!`
you could also do: 
`b = round(a,2)`

So to beautify your dictionary:

```
newdict = {}
for x in d:
    if isinstance(d[x],float):
        newdict[x] = round(d[x],2)
    else:
        newdict[x] = d[x]
```

you could also do:

```
newdict = {}
for x in d:
    if isinstance(d[x],float):
        newdict[x] = float("%.2f" % d[x])
    else:
        newdict[x] = d[x]
```

though the first one is recommended!

Comment: I think you meant something like `if isinstance(d[x],float):`. Regardless. another problem is that this changes the values in dictionary being processed -- probably undesirable.

Comment: oh, yes sorry that is exactly what i mean. I made an edit check it out